# How can I access a specific json object using jquery and json?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having a problem trying to return a specific record using jQuery and JSON. I'm passing a variable to the function and want to output only the data matching the id I've set when the function is executed.

Right now, my function looks like this:

```
function getEffectsData(myNum){
    $.getJSON("jsonscript.php", { id: +myNum },function(data){
       var x = data.x;
       //DO SOME STUFF
    });
}
```

The JSON output looks like this:

`{"stuff": [ { "id":1, "x":3, "y":6, "z":-6 },{ "id":2, "x":2, "y":7, "z":-3 }]}`

The only thing I know is that the correct variable is being passed to the function. After that, nothing happens. Very new at this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I appreciate everybody's input on this. To clarify, I am trying to return the data from only the object that's id matches myNum. I want to be able to access all of the data from that object, but only that object. I have no idea where that object will be in the array. I simplified the ids and the data in my question to help clarify the problem.

Thanks again.

Comment: uh...isn't +myNum a syntax error?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Which data do you want to access from the JSON string? `data.x` is obviously wrong.

Comment: @sje397: If `myNum` is a number (not a string or object) then NO. It is just math. `-myNum` wouldn't be an error either.

Comment: @Felix ah yeah...i'd blame the vodka but i think it's more that it's such an uncommon (and, i'll add, useless) syntax :) thanks

Comment: I want to access only the data that matches the id set with myNum. So if myNum = 2, I want only the data from the object with the id of 2. Does that clarify anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access x from your JSON like this:

```
var x1 = data.stuff[0].x; // the first object's x key
var x2 = data.stuff[1].x; // the second object's x key
```

Because your JSON tree looks like this:

```
{ // base object
    "stuff": [ // array
    { // 0.: object
        "id": 1,  // key => value
        "x" : 3,  // key => value
        "y" : 6,  // key => value
        "z" : -6  // key => value
    },
    { // 1.: object
        "id": 2,  // key => value
        "x" : 2,  // key => value
        "y" : 7,  // key => value
        "z" : -3  // key => value
    }]
}
```

So with `data.stuff[0].x` you select `stuff` object then it's `first` element and then its `x` key.

But If you want to handle all the `x` key for example, then you need to loop through the `stuff` array by a simple `for` loop or the [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method.

---

> ### UPDATE

As for your question. If you want to get the object with id `myNum` you have **2 possibilities**:

1. if you possess `jsonscript.php` you can send the data only with the correct id from the server, because you pass the id to it by `{ id: +myNum }` which is the second parameter of [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B)
2. You loop through the data until you find the object with the correct id

   ```
   var object; 
   $.each(data.stuff, function(i, obj) {
     if (obj.id === myNum) object = obj;
   });
   // now object is the one with the right id
   ```

Comment: I'm only trying to access the object with the same id that matches myNum. I have no idea where it will be within the array as the actual ids are non-sequential.

Comment: How do I pass the JS variable myNum to the PHP mysql query? I'm making the (probably wrong) assumption that it would be "WHERE id = myNum". 

This is what I'm trying to do though.

Comment: Why do I get `Unexpected token ;` on this?

Comment: there was a ')' missing at the end of step **2.**

Answer (score 1):

It's an array under `stuff`, so you would need something like this:

```
function getEffectsData(myNum){
    $.getJSON("jsonscript.php", { id: +myNum },function(data){
       $.each(data.stuff, function(i, obj) {
         var x = obj.x;
         //DO SOME STUFF
       });
    });
}
```

If you're after the very first `x` you can do `data.stuff[0].x`, but I think you'd want to loop through here.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
var x = data[0].x;
```

or

```
var x = data[1]['x'];
```

for instance.

Comment: Actually, @Nick's answer is right.  There's a `stuff` property that has an array value.  Each of the objects in this array have an `x` property.