# Append data acquired from JSON to a Raphael object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

*Solved the question on my own, see answer*

Using jQuery 3.2.1 and Raphael 2.1.1, if this matters

In my Raphael .js I first create some objects without any data and push them into an array, e. g. (.attr omitted):

```
var objarr = [];

    var obj1 = rsr.path("M ... z");
    objarr.push(obj1);
```

After this, I want to take data from a JSON file (an array named "regions" of multiple entries that consist of multiple key-value pairs (validated through [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)) and append it as data by id. It looks like this:

```
{
    "regions": [{
            "id": "0",
            "var1": "foo1",
            "var2": "bar1",
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "var1": "foo2",
            "var2": "bar2",
        },
        // And so on for every object
    ]
}
```

I use the following code (localhost is used because otherwise I get a cross-access error:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objarr.length; i++)
{
    var jq = $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/data.json",{id: +i},function(t){
        console.log( "success" );
    })
    .done(function(objdata){
            console.log("success2");
            $.each(objdata.regions, function(key, val){
                objarr[i].data(key,val);
            });
        })
    .fail(function(t){
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function(t){
        console.log("complete");
    });
}
```

The console gives me both successes, but after this I get an error "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined". `alert(key)` and `alert(val)` give `0` and `[object Object]` respectively for every call. I tried adding the following to `.done`:

```
var items = [];
            $.each(objdata.regions, function(key, val){
                items.push("id" + key + ":" + val);
                console.log(items);
            });
```

The result was a string that went `["id0:[object Object]"]`,`["id0:[object Object]", "id1:[object Object]"]` and so on until it had objarr.length ids, repeating the needed amount of times. If I add `[i]` to `objdata.regions`, I get no console messages about items[] content at all.

I also found two somewhat closely related questions (["1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203417/how-can-i-access-a-specific-json-object-using-jquery-and-json) and ["2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291584/get-json-data-with-ajax-and-then-modify-raphael-js-script)), checked the jQuery documentation for `.getJSON();` and Raphael documentation for `Element.data();`. I've tried the following to check validity of my calls:

- `console.log(objdata)` in the beginning of `.done` -- returns full base object of JSON data
- `console.log(objdata.regions)` in the beginning of `.done` --  returns array of objects of JSON data
- `console.log(objdata.regions[i])` in the beginning of `.done` --  returns *undefined*
- `console.log(objdata.regions[0])` in the beginning of `.done` --  returns first object (works for every object)

I've used objdata.regions[0] in the snippet with `items[]` and the adding seems to work properly (console shows the keys and values being added to the array). However, it still doesn't work with `objarr[i].data(key,val)` (as well as `""+key` and `"$key"`).

I have two questions:
1. How do I acquire the key-value pairs properly while looping?
2. How do I append these pairs as data to a Raphael object?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `for` loop inside `.done()` and everything is appended successfully:

```
.done(function(objdata){
        for (var i = 0; i < objarr.length; i++)
        {
            console.log("success2");
            $.each(objdata.regions[i],function(key, val){
                objarr[i].data(key, val);
            });
        }
    })
```